# Errata in Convex Analysis and Minimization Algorithms by Hiriart-Urruty and Lemaréchal.

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis, book-recommendation, big-list, reference-works

Hiriart-Urruty and Lemaréchal have written  Convex Analysis and Minimization Algorithms I and II. Is there an errata list for these books?

Comment: Lamarachal -> Lemaréchal